# How can i inject a new label into existing metrics like kube_node_info or kube_pod_info

Tags: linux, kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, monitoring

i'm building a grafana dashboard where i can monitor multiple cluster in one place. The problem is that when i try to filter metrics based on the cluster name but it doesn't exist in the metrics like kube_node_info and kube_pod_info. So far i created two labels but they are not injected in the mentioned metrics just in some other metrics that i do not find useful, many thanks.

Here's how i created the label:

```
- job_name: 'cluster-1'
  static_configs:
  - targets: ['localhost:9100']
    labels:
      cluster_name: 'cluster-1'
```

Comment: To clarify your expectation, adding the `static_config` that you show, **all** metrics from the target (`localhost:9100`) **will** have the label `cluster_name="cluster-1"` added. Example, there's likely a metric `up`. You will now be able to query `up{cluster_name="cluster-1",instance="localhost:9100"}`. **NOTE** The `job_name` of (all?) `scrape_config` target metrics is added as a label too. In this case, because `job_name` == `cluster_name` == `cluster-1`, your metrics from this target should all have `cluster_name="cluster-1"` and `job_name="cluster-1"` label-values.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The problem was that the metrics i wanted to query were generated by kube state metrics pod on port 8080. The configuration i provided above are for node exporter. Now i can see cluster name in kube_"anything" metrics and your answer cleared it out for me. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm pleased to hear that it helped.

Comment: If you're using Prom Operator, you can use `externalLabels` in the `Prometheus` spec. From the docs: `The labels to add to any time series or alerts when communicating with external systems (federation, remote storage, Alertmanager)`. https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/main/Documentation/api.md